# return regresa respuesta seguido de Undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo 3 funciones: una saca el máximo, otra el mínimo, y la tercera saca el mínimo, el máximo y el promedio, todo en una sola respuesta. El problema es que cuando quiero retornar me sale en una array y yo lo necesitaba como respuestas separadas, entonces creé una array llamada *resultado* dentro de la función, y a la hora de invocar `return`, invocaba `return resultado.forEach(item => console.log(item));` y me da la respuesta correcta, pero seguido de `undefined` ¿por qué? ¿cómo arreglo eso?
Mi código completo es el siguiente:

```
const donaciones = [5, 15, 22, 25, 30, 52, 5, 1, 0];

function max(array) {
  let maximo = 0;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const items of array) {
    if (items > maximo) {
      maximo = items;
    }
  }
  return maximo;
}

function min(array) {
  let minimo = max(array);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const items of array) {
    if (items < minimo) {
      minimo = items;
    }
  }
  return minimo;
}
const minimo = min(donaciones);
const maximo = max(donaciones);

function promedio(minimo, maximo, array) {
  let prom = 0;
  let prom2 = 0;
  let prom3 = 0;
  let resultado;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const element of array) {
    prom += element;
    prom2 = prom - minimo;
    prom3 = prom2 - maximo;
    resultado = [minimo, maximo, (prom3 / (array.length - 2))];
  }
  return resultado.forEach(item => console.log(item));
}
console.log(max(donaciones));
console.log(min(donaciones));
console.log(promedio(minimo, maximo, donaciones));
```

pero lo importante es esta parte

```
const minimo = min(donaciones);
const maximo = max(donaciones);

function promedio(minimo, maximo, array) {
  let prom = 0;
  let prom2 = 0;
  let prom3 = 0;
  let resultado;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const element of array) {
    prom += element;
    prom2 = prom - minimo;
    prom3 = prom2 - maximo;
    resultado = [minimo, maximo, (prom3 / (array.length - 2))];
  }
  return resultado.forEach(item => console.log(item));
}
console.log(promedio(minimo, maximo, donaciones));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos cosas erróneas e incoherentes en tu código:

1. El *`undefined`* ocurre porque tratas de imprimir algo que ya se imprimió. Es decir, dentro de la función tienes un `console.log()` que imprimiría la salida, y cuando intentas el segundo `console.log()` ya no hay nada que imprimir y por tanto la salida es *`undefined`* (ver un ejemplo muy sencillo al final de la respuesta).
2. Si la intención es imprimir dentro de la función, no tiene ningún sentido que dicha función haga un `return`. Eso tendría sentido si necesitaras usar `resultado` en el contexto de llamada de la función.

Si quieres imprimir dentro, esta bastará:

```js
const donaciones = [5, 15, 22, 25, 30, 52, 5, 1, 0];

function max(array) {
  let maximo = 0;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const items of array) {
    if (items > maximo) {
      maximo = items;
    }
  }
  return maximo;
}

function min(array) {
  let minimo = max(array);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const items of array) {
    if (items < minimo) {
      minimo = items;
    }
  }
  return minimo;
}
const minimo = min(donaciones);
const maximo = max(donaciones);

function promedio(minimo, maximo, array) {
  let prom = 0;
  let prom2 = 0;
  let prom3 = 0;
  let resultado;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const element of array) {
    prom += element;
    prom2 = prom - minimo;
    prom3 = prom2 - maximo;
    
    resultado = [minimo, maximo, (prom3 / (array.length - 2))];
  }
   resultado.forEach(item =>  console.log(item));
}
console.log(max(donaciones));
console.log(min(donaciones));
promedio(minimo, maximo, donaciones);
```

Observa que aquí `promedio(minimo, maximo, donaciones);`, quitamos el `console.log()` porque éste ya ocurre dentro de la función.

Otra posibilidad es que retornes `resultado` desde dentro de la función, en ese caso sí tendría sentido el `return` y podríamos imprimir *in situ* leyendo el array retornado:

```js
const donaciones = [5, 15, 22, 25, 30, 52, 5, 1, 0];

function max(array) {
  let maximo = 0;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const items of array) {
    if (items > maximo) {
      maximo = items;
    }
  }
  return maximo;
}

function min(array) {
  let minimo = max(array);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const items of array) {
    if (items < minimo) {
      minimo = items;
    }
  }
  return minimo;
}
const minimo = min(donaciones);
const maximo = max(donaciones);

function promedio(minimo, maximo, array) {
  let prom = 0;
  let prom2 = 0;
  let prom3 = 0;
  let resultado;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const element of array) {
    prom += element;
    prom2 = prom - minimo;
    prom3 = prom2 - maximo;
    
    resultado = [minimo, maximo, (prom3 / (array.length - 2))];
  }
   return resultado;
}
console.log(max(donaciones));
console.log(min(donaciones));
promedio(minimo, maximo, donaciones).forEach(item =>  console.log(item));
```

---

### Un ejemplo simple del problema de undefined

Observa este pequeño ejemplo:

```js
console.log(console.log("¡Ya me imprimieron, no me vuelvas a imprimir!"));
```

El `console.log()` interno imprime la cadena, y cuando el `console.log()` externo trata de imprimir ya no hay nada que imprimir, resultando en `undefined`.

Comment: vaya, me has dejado en claro una duda que ya llevaba tiempo, era comun que me pasara ese problema, igual yo tambien lo resolvi de otra manera, adjunto codigo ```function promedio(maximo, minimo, array) {
  let prom = 0;
  let prom2 = 0;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const element of array) {
    if (element === minimo || element === maximo) {
      console.log(element);
    }
    if (element > minimo && element < maximo) {
      prom += element;
      prom2 += 1;
    }
  }
  return prom / prom2;
}console.log(promedio(maximo, minimo, donaciones));
```

Comment: hay disculpe, pero es que no se ni como enviar bien el codigo jaja, gracias por responder igual, apenas llevo medio mes aprendiendo javascript de manera autodidactica y la verdad se aprecia que explique esto, ya que no era la primera vez que tenia ese error undefined, y me ha ayudado un monton a comprender la logica de retrun y console.log, muchas gracias

Comment: @BrandonJoaoCastillo me alegro de que te haya servido. Bienvenido y no dudes en preguntar en Stackoverflow cuando estés bloqueado en algún código. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te imprime *undefined* porque la función *promedio* en realidad no está devolviendo nada. Estás haciendo un `return foreach` (foreach, igual que console.log, no devuelve ningún valor, lo que en javascript se traduce en que devuelve *undefined*)

Las lineas que ves impresas correctas, son las que se imprimen dentro de *promedio*, y luego el *undefined* que ves es resultado del console.log() que tienes por encima, en esta linea

```
console.log(promedio(minimo, maximo, donaciones));
```